# Combining numpys fancy indexing with slicing

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-indexing

I currently have a two-dimensional numpy array of shape `(m, n)`. Furthermore, I have two `(m, p)` arrays of indices `i1` and `i2`. The indices are always contiguous!

```
import numpy as np
t = np.array([[-1, -1,  0,  0,  1,  2,  2],
              [-1, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  3],
              [0,  0,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3]])

i1 = np.array([3, 2, 2])
i2 = np.array([4, 3, 3])
```

How do I use the arrays `i1` and `i2` to slice `t` in order to obtain the following sub-matrix?

```
expected_t = np.array([
                      [0, 1],
                      [0, 1],
                      [1, 2]
])
```

That is

```
expected_t[0, :] = t[0, i1[0]:i2[0]]
expected_t[1, :] = t[1, i1[1]:i2[1]]
expected_t[2, :] = t[2, i1[2]:i2[2]]
```

Furthermore, is this possible to do without copying the data by creating a view?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: I don't think it's *natively* possible. Are you looking for solutions if they do require copying?

Answer (score 1):

Use fancy indexing in numpy:

```
t[np.arange(3).reshape(3,1), np.vstack((i1,i2)).T]
```

OR

```
t[np.arange(3), np.vstack((i1,i2))].T
```

Both will have the result:

```
array([[0, 1],
   [0, 1],
   [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this, but I don't know if it exists a fastest way of indexing following the example :

```
import numpy as np
t = np.array([[-1, -1,  0,  0,  1,  2,  2],
              [-1, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  3],
              [0,  0,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3]])

i1 = np.array([3, 2, 2])
i2 = np.array([4, 3, 3])

output = [] 
for i, (min_, max_) in enumerate(zip(i1, i2)):
    output.append(t[i, min_:max_+1])

expected_t = np.array(output)
```

Or shorter :

```
expected_t = np.array([t[i, j:k+1] for (i,j,k) in zip(range(len(t)), i1, i2)])
```

Comment: Worth noting this doesn't satisfy OP's criterion of outputting a view (not that I'm convinced it's possible).

Comment: Yes, but I also don't think it's possible to get a direct view of the array in such a way.